# I'm facing error(could not find driver) while creating the database in symfony 5

Tags: symfony5

.env

DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:123456@127.0.0.1:3306/symphart"

doctrine.yaml

doctrine:
dbal:
url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

```
    # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
    # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
    #server_version: '13'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

error:
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 128:

An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

In Exception.php line 18:

could not find driver

In PDOConnection.php line 38:

could not find driver

command : php bin/console doctrine:database:create

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? "Could not find driver" sounds like you haven't enabled the proper PHP extensions

Comment: Yup looks like you are missing the pdo mysql extension https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Also, you should specify the server version in your database url with someithing like this `DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"`